# Adding Fragment to containers with the same ID

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragmentmanager

I have a ViewPager to implement swipe between "holder" Fragments. And inside them I need to add multiple Fragments to their respective containers.

The problem is, Im using `FragmentTransaction.add(containerID, fragment);`, but since there are multiple holder Fragments in the ViewPager, all the Fragments get added on the same holder Fragment, and not in the one that is calling to add them.

Anyone has an idea on a good practice to go around this problem?

Here is the code where I add the Fragments inside the holder fragment.

```
arrayFragments = new ArrayList<DiaAgendaFragment>();
DiaAgendaFragment objFragment;
FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction transaction = fm.beginTransaction();

//this will be set accordingly later for each fragment
Time dataFragment = new Time();
dataFragment.setToNow();

//instantiate and set fragments
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {

    objFragment = DiaAgendaFragment.newInstance(5, dataFragment);
    arrayFragments.add(objFragment);
    //pega a View pelo nome e adiciona o fragment
    transaction.add(getActivity().getResources().getIdentifier("agenda5d_activity_fragment"+i, "id", getActivity().getPackageName()), arrayFragments.get(i));
    //codigo de teste
    dataFragment.monthDay += 1;
}
transaction.commit();
```

Comment: For my purpose I had a fragment with scrolview as root layout and i used to add fragments inside a loop directly on the scrollview you can try something like this

Comment: You have to use the child `FragmentManager` when adding `Fragments` inside of another `Fragment`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use the child `FragmentManager` if you want to add `Fragments` to another `Fragment`. Using the normal `FragmentManager` will not work as you found out yourself.

In your `Fragment`:

```
FragmentManager manager = getChildFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction();
...
transaction.commit();
```

Comment: That seems about right. One last thing before I mark your answer correct. getChildFragmentManager() is API lvl 17. I'm trying to target my minimum API to 11 so I'm using support.v13. And as of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21867894/where-is-getchildfragmentmanager-in-support-library-v13) question I would need to go back using full support.v4 for this?

Comment: Yes you need to use the `Fragments` from the support library.